# Unable to set schema.registry.group.id by environment variable using docker (ECS) in Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

The following env var is passed to the Amazon ECS docker container:

SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID, however, the group id is not picked up by Schema Registry and the default schema-registry value is used:

```
[2023-04-25 14:51:02,801] INFO [Schema registry clientId=sr-1, groupId=schema-registry]
```

All other env vars passed to the confluent schema registry in docker work as expected, e.g. SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS

Anyone come across this before? Seems a niche issue!

Comment: Note: AWS Glue can also run a Schema Registry for Kafka, so you may not need ECS or this image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different group ids...

`schema.registry.group.id` would be set by `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID`

`kafkastore.group.id` would be set by `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_GROUP_ID`

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#sr-long-configuration

[There is no config for just `group.id`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html#schemaregistry-config). Which is what your variable would try to configure.